# Javascript Stop working on hard page reload in MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I have developed an app using MeteorJS. Everything is working fine. A small issue i am facing i.e. When i hard reload the page custom javascript stop working.

I have implemented table sorting javascript library (http://tablesorter.com/docs/) in application. After reloading the page sorting stops working but when i navigate to another page and come back to that same page it is working fine.

Here is the code that i have used to apply sorting on tables.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table").tablesorter();
});
```

I also tried adding this code in onRendered method of MeteorJS

```
Template.captable.onRendered(function () {
    $("table").tablesorter();
});
```

When i execute **$("table").tablesorter();** in console after hard reloading page it start working.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are calling `.tablesorter()` before all data has arrived.

When you load a Meteor page for the first time (as with a hard reload) all subscriptions are reset to empty. So there is no data available on the client.

Then your app javascript loads and starts to execute: You call subscribe to fetch data, and your template is rendered very shortly afterwards, but **before** the subscription data has actually arrived from the server.

Your template is the re-rendered as the data arrives, but the `onRendered()` has already fired once, and does not fire again.

What you need to do is wait with calling `.tablesorter()` until your subscription is `.ready()`. Since `onRendered()` is not reactive, you need to define an autorun to do this. If you follow [the recommended pattern for template subscriptions](https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#organizing-subscriptions), it looks like this:

```
Template.captable.onCreated( function() {
    this.subscribe('captable'); // ...or whatever your publication name is.
});

Template.captable.onRendered(function () {
    this.autorun( function() {
        if( Template.instance().subscriptionsReady() ) $("table").tablesorter();
    });
});
```

Comment: What about simply using the `onReady` callback of [`subscribe()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-subscribe)?

Comment: Well, if the subscribe is a template level subscription that is better because of no autorun, but the OP did not show how he subscribes, and my personal preference is doing things inside the Template to have that context.

Comment: @JesperWe  i didn't understand **captableSubscription.ready()** can you please explain it.

Comment: OK,I changed the answer a bit, to show how to do it according to the MeteorGuide principles (linked in the answer)

Comment: @JesperWe I implemented your code into my code. It shows **TypeError: this.subscriptionsReady is not a function** in window console.

Comment: I changed the answer to one that works better (not context dependent)